# c Allegro ISO error Using & and integers yet not working

Tags: c++, allegro

I am making an allegro game using my own logic and primitive engine. Im a trying to make gravity and contact with tiles from an array. To be able to change values of a class from another class, i had to use the reference symbol '&'. After compiling i receive this error
**ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer at line 29 of gravity.cpp**
Here is are the headers for the gravity class and gravity.cpp plus player.h and player.cpp.

gravity.h

```
#ifndef GRAVITY_H
#define GRAVITY_H
#include<allegro.h>
#include<fstream>
#include "Global.h"

class Gravity
{
public:
    Gravity();
    ~Gravity();
    bool canJump,JumpAgain,OnSolidTile,Collision;
    int GravSpeed;
    void LoadMap(const char*filename);
    void Init();
    void Grav_Collision(int &x,int &y,int &x2,int &y2,int Gravspeed,bool canJump,bool JumpAgain,bool OnSolidTile,bool Collision);
    private:
    int loadCounterX,loadCounterY;
    int ColMap[100][100];
    int MapSizeX,MapSizeY;
    };

    #endif // GRAVITY_H
```

gravity.cpp
**Error is on this file**
    #include "gravity.h" // class's header file

```
Gravity::Gravity()
{

}


Gravity::~Gravity()
{

}
void Gravity::Init()
{
 loadCounterX = loadCounterY = 0;
};
void Gravity::Grav_Collision(int &x,int &y,int &x2,int &y2,int Gravspeed,bool canJump,bool JumpAgain,bool OnSolidTile,bool Collision)
{
 for(int i = 0;i < MapSizeX;i++)
 {
     for(int j = 0;j < MapSizeY;j++)
     {
      if(ColMap[i][j] = 1)
      {
          //Collision
          if(&y2 < j*BlockSize)--**This IS where the error is found **--
          {
            Collision = true;       
          }
          else
          {
           Collision = false;    
          }      
      }        
     }        
 }
};
 void Gravity::LoadMap(const char*filename)
 {
 std::ifstream openfile (filename);
 if (openfile.is_open())
 {
 openfile >> MapSizeX >> MapSizeY;
 while (!openfile.eof())
 {
     openfile >> ColMap[loadCounterX][loadCounterY];   
     loadCounterX ++;
     if (loadCounterX >= MapSizeX)
     {
        loadCounterX = 0;
        loadCounterY ++;
     }
 }                       
   loadCounterX = loadCounterY = 0;
 } 
 else
 {
 allegro_message ("NO Collision FILE");    
 } 
 };
```

player.h

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H
#include <allegro.h>
#include "Global.h"

class player
{
public:
    player();
    ~player();
    void Init();
    void Update();
    void Draw(BITMAP*buffer,int c1,int c2,int c3);
    void Input();
    //Variable
    int x;
    int x2;
    int y;
    int y2;
    int speed;
    char dir;
    BITMAP*buffer;
    private:
    int c1;
    int c2;
    int c3;
    };

   #endif // PLAYER_H
```

player.cpp

```
#include "player.h" // class's header file

// class constructor
player::player()
{
// insert your code here
}

// class destructor
player::~player()
{
// insert your code here
}
void player::Init()
{
 x = 9;
 y = 9;
 speed = 1;
 dir = 0;
};
void player::Draw(BITMAP*buffer,int c1,int c2,int c3)
{
 textprintf(buffer, font, x-30, y-10, makecol(255,0,0), "x: %03i", x);
 textprintf(buffer, font, x-30, y-20, makecol(255,0,0), "y: %03i", y);
 rectfill(buffer,x,y,x + 5,y + 5,makecol(c1,c2,c3));
};
void player::Input()
{
 //Input
 if(KLeft && x >= 0)
 {
         dir = 'l'; 
 }
 else if(KRIGHT && x <= SW)
 {
       dir = 'r';      
 }
 else if(KUP && y >= 0)
 {
       dir = 'u';      
 }
 else if(KDOWN && y <= SH)
 {
       dir = 'd';      
 }
 else
 {
       dir = 'e';
 }
 //Output

 if(dir == 'l')
 {
     x += -speed;       
 }
 if(dir == 'r')
 {
   x  += speed;   
 }
 if(dir == 'u')
 {
     y += -speed;       
 }
 if(dir == 'd')
 {
   y  += speed;   
 }

};
void player::Update()
{
 player::Input();

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the error line you probably mean `y2 < j*BlockSize` instead of `&y2 < j*BlockSize`. You're comparing an integer with the address of the variable y (that is, a pointer). And that's exactly what the compiler complains about.

Comment: Yup it works. Now i have to fix my gravity engine :( Thank you for your help. All of you

Comment: @WilliamChantrillPaul You're welcome. Welcome to stackoverflow. Please accept the most useful answer to your question so others can benefit from it. Also consider upvoting/downvoting helpful/unhelpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

The error message clearly tells you what's wrong.

In this line:

```
if(&y2 < j*BlockSize)
```

Since `y2` is an integer `&y2` yields a pointer and `j*BlockSize` is an integer. Hence, compiler tells you that comparing integer and pointer makes no sense. Just drop the `&`:

```
if(y2 < j*BlockSize)
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler tell you every thing that you need to know, in that line `&y2` get address of `y2` and you are comparing it with `j*BlockSize` that is an integral and compiler say why you want to compare an address with a number?

Honestly I don't read your code and don't know what you are doing there, so if you want to compare value of `y2` with `j*BlockSize` just do it as `y2 < j*BlockSize`, in C++ references require no accessor and you can read/write their value as a normal value